# Confirm user password before registration

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if user entered password correctly both times, but when I press submit button when passwords don't match in the password fields, it still registers me successfully.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password2']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '" . $username . "'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again. </p>";
    }

    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2'])
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, that PASSWORD is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
    } else
    {
        $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $email . "')");
        if ($registerquery)
        {
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
            echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;login.php' />";
        } else
        {
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
?>

<h1>Member Registration</h1>
<p>Thanks for visiting! Please either Register below, or
    <a href="login.php">click here to Sing In</a>.
</p>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container" style="width:250px; height:100px;">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post"
          action="registrationsimple.php" name="registerform"
          id="registerform">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/><br/>

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"
                   id="password" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Password"/><br/>
            <label for="password2">Password2:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password2"
                   id="password2" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Password"/><br/>

            <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" ;/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="register" id="register"
                   value="Register" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                   style="padding:10px;top-margin:20px;"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How is `$username` being pulled in before you query? That's the question. Plus, I hope this isn't going to be a live site.

Comment: it's just for practice , but why it should not be ?

Comment: Plain text password storage and not using prepared statements to query with. Guaranteed hack.

Comment: Actually, you're using MD5 and noticed it just now. It's just as bad as using plain text passwords. `password_hash()` is a much better and safer function to use.

Comment: my first interaction with php was 5 days ago , i dont know what is what yet . but when i checked my db it stored encrypted password there so i assumed that was the right way .  thanks for the tip

Comment: It's not good practice to validate user password in "match or not". sorry to comment that, I just say something if this is good or not for our mates

Answer (score 2):

I found many confusing lines in your codes:

First, You declare for password A, but not password B. So, it should be:

```
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
$password2 = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
```

Second, You declared the variables but not using it to validate, so it should be:

```
if ($password != $password2) {
```

Third, The `IF` and `ELSE` structure is not (confused what should I say), so pls check again THAT structure. that makes PHP & browser gets confused too.

Forth, You have `email` which you don't include it there in PHP scripts.

From the statements above,  I suggest you to see this follows:

```
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
$password2 = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

if(empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']) && empty($_POST['password2'])){
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, you must fill all the fields. Please go back and try again.</p>";
    }
elseif ($password!=$password2) {
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, that PASSWORD is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
    }
elseif (//validate the email here){
    //.....................
    }
else{ 
    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1) {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again. </p>";
        }
    else{
        $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
        if($registerquery) {
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
            echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;login.php' />";
            }
        else{
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
            }       
        }
    }
//REMOVE ELSE IN THIS FOLLOWS!
else{
    //............ ?????????????????????
    }
?>
```

And at Last, Please change into MySQLI ext or (best recom = PDO).

Answer (score 0):

Malformatted:

```
<input 
  type="text" name="email" 
  id="email" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Email Adress" 
/>

<br />

<input 
  type="submit" name="register" 
  id="register" value="Register" 
  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" 
  style="padding:10px;top-margin:20px;" 
/>
```

Logic appears to work as you intended.